# Best way to send large amounts of text in a Restful service

Tags: java, rest, pdf, text, apache-tika

I am developing an API in java that receives as parameters the location of a pdf file. Returns PDF text content.

I started by using Apache Tika to extract the text. Because PDFs can be long, I wanted to know the best, fastest, and most accurate way to get the text back. Since it is a Restful API. I return it to json.

Compress text? Convert to bytes? What would be the best format to return?

Code sample:

```
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler( );
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata( );
        InputStream inputstream = new URL( test ).openStream( );
        ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext( );

        //parsing the document using PDF parser
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser( );
        parser.parse( inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext );

        //getting the content of the document
        System.out.println( "Contents of the PDF :" + handler.toString( ) );
```

How could I extract and send large amounts of text? Or control the maximum to send? PDF with hundreds of text pages, what would be the best option?

Thank you.

Comment: If you (by some means) extract the text as lets say UTF-16 text from an 1000 page PDF, I would not worry about size too much. If we say that each line in the pdf has about 100 characters (in reality, it is less) and each page has about 30 lines (again, in reality it is less), the file would be roughly 6 MB in size (2 byte/character * 100 characters/line * 30 lines/page * 1000 pages).

Comment: If you return plain text, check [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). This means checking for the Accept-Encoding header (browser can accept compressed content), and wrap a GZipOutputStream around the original output stream.

Comment: @JoopEggen The answer goes in json format. One of the fields is the extracted text. Compressing the response with gzip can not bring problems to the client side? In order to function, the client will not have to send in the request the header as it accepts gzip compression?

Comment: If the client's browser accepts gzip, the browser unzips the content. And most browsers do, and add the corresponding header to the HTTP request. Otherwise the original content must be delivered. As the net is the slowest factor, this can easily help; hotter CPU but shorter request/response time, so good for the server.

Comment: @JoopEggen Yes, in the case of browsers there should be no problem. But this API is to be called especially by java client, javascript. We're afraid it will create difficulties for those who create the API client, you know? Do you think it will be clear to users who want to create an API client in java or js?

Comment: It is little coding effort, and testing. But let us reconsider: maybe the API users would find a zip file tolerable? Or a docx/odx (zip too?). I hope someone comes with a better answer.